# Question on Permutation/Combination

Tags: permutations, combinations

A committee of 12 is to be formed from 9 women and 8 men. In how many ways this can be done if at least 5 women have to be included in a committee?

I don't want to know how to answer this. I know that we have to take cases (5 women, 6 women, 7 women and 8 women) and add them up.

I want to know why I'm not getting the same result if I take 5 women first and then merge the women and men and take 7 people from them.
This will give me ${9\choose5}\times{12\choose7}$ but the answer given is 6062, which I do get by taking cases.

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer as you noted is:

$${9\choose5}{8\choose7}+{9\choose6}{8\choose6}+{9\choose7}{8\choose5}+{9\choose8}{8\choose4}+{9\choose9}{8\choose3}$$

Your alternate proposal is:

$${9\choose5}{12\choose7}$$

This is equal to:

$${9\choose5}{8\choose7}{5\choose5}+{9\choose6}{8\choose6}{6\choose5}+{9\choose7}{8\choose5}{7\choose5}+{9\choose8}{8\choose4}{8\choose5}+{9\choose9}{8\choose3}{9\choose5}$$

In other words, for each possible committee, you are over-counting that possibility by $n\choose5$ times, where $n$ is the number of women in that particular committee.  Do you see why?

Comment: Note: I didn't numerically check these equalities.  Wouldn't mind a side check by someone with a spare minute.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

You are overcounting, and let us see why.

Well, suppose your ladies are  named "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i", and your men are named "j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q" (I apologize, indeed I named my fishes after letters of the Cyrillic script, so this does happen).

Suppose we choose 5 women first, let us say $a,b,c,d,e$. Then, later on you combine the rest and choose seven more people. Let us say I chose $f,g,j,k,l,m,n$, which is five men and two women, from the remaining bunch, to make a committee of twelve members, namely $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,j,k,l,m,n$.

Now, let's assume I went this way : I chose five women first, say $c,d,e,f,g$, and then I combined the rest of the people, and chose seven out of these, who turned out to be $a,b,j,k,l,m,n$. Then, this makes a committee of twelve members, which is $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,j,k,l,m,n$.

The same committee has been formed in two "different" ways by your methodology. Hence, you are likely to be overcounting. This is reflected in your answer, which is $99,792$, a huge overestimate on the proposed answer of six thousand sixty two.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the $9$ women's names are $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I.$

And the $8$ men's names are $J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q.$

At your first stage you pick $5$ women; suppose these are $A,B,C,D,E.$

At your second stage you pick $7$ others, who may be either women or men; suppose these are $F,G,J,K,L,M,N$ --- thus two women and five men.

But alternatively, suppose at your first stage the $5$ women you picked were $A,B,C,F,G.$

And then at your second stage you pick $7$ others and they are $D,E,J,K,L,M,N$ --- thus two women and five men.

Either way, you get the *same* set of seven women and five men.

But by your second method, you have counted this particular outcome twice (so far....). That's what's wrong with your second method.

Comment: Actually, you count that particular outcome $21$ times, not twice.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

Others have explained what is wrong with your calculation. Here is a shorter *right* approach than what you sketch:

There are $\binom{17}{12}$ possible committees if we ignore the gender quota.

The only way there can possibly be *less than* $5$ women on the committee is if all $8$ men are on it -- so $\binom{9}{4}$ of the $\binom{17}{12}$ possible committees are invalid.

The number of *valid* committees is therefore
$$ \binom{17}{12} - \binom{9}{4}. $$